# Dynamically imported module doesn't generate separate chunk

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I import a module via dynamic imports:

```
import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "comp-abc" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
    './comp-abc.jsx'
)
```

But after building via webpack, there isn't a separate chunk generated for `comp-abc.jsx` that's loaded. Instead, it's just included in the main bundle. Do I need to add an additional plugin or loader?

Repo containing webpack configs + working issue: https://github.com/catc/code-splitting-poc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was using `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` using instead of the correct [babel-plugin-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/).

See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5703#issuecomment-330964922 for original github issue.